# How to replace multiple NaN rows in pandas dataframe with a single NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series, where one of the columns contains mostly NaN.
The dataframe is quite large, so handling all these NaNs is becoming a burden.
If I simply drop all of them, plots are getting completely messed up with interpolation between remaining data points.

Here's a short example of what I have:

```
        v           x
0.0000  0.000000    NaN
0.0002  0.062791    NaN
0.0004  0.125333    NaN
0.0006  0.187381    95.0
0.0008  0.248690    NaN
0.0010  0.309017    NaN
0.0012  0.368125    NaN
0.0014  0.425779    88.0
0.0016  0.481754    85.0
0.0018  0.535827    91.0
0.0020  0.587785    NaN
0.0022  0.637424    NaN
0.0024  0.684547    NaN
0.0026  0.728969    99.0
...
```

and what I want to achieve:

```
        v           x
0.0004  0.125333    NaN
0.0006  0.187381    95.0
0.0012  0.368125    NaN
0.0014  0.425779    88.0
0.0016  0.481754    85.0
0.0018  0.535827    91.0
0.0024  0.684547    NaN
0.0026  0.728969    99.0
...
```

Iterating through rows is not an option, as it will be way to slow, but I can't figure out any reasonable approach.
Any ideas?

---

*A dataset example (rather short) to work with:*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f=50
Tmax = 1
fs= 5000

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0, Tmax, 1/fs), data={'x':np.random.randint(0,100, size=int(fs*Tmax))})
df['v'] = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*df.index)

# Most of "x" is NaN
df.loc[df['x']<75, 'x'] = np.NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed and [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and chain by `|` for bitwise OR:

```
df = df[df.x.shift(-1).notna() | df.x.notna()]
print (df)
               v     x
0.0004  0.125333   NaN
0.0006  0.187381  95.0
0.0012  0.368125   NaN
0.0014  0.425779  88.0
0.0016  0.481754  85.0
0.0018  0.535827  91.0
0.0024  0.684547   NaN
0.0026  0.728969  99.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a new variable temp by using shift method on x.

```
df['temp'] = df.x.shift(-1)
```

Then filter the rows where either x or temp is not null.

```
df[(~df.x.isnull())|(~df.temp.isnull())]
```

Since this approach uses inbuilt functions & filtering rather than loops, it should be faster.

Comment: You could chain the methods there to avoid creating a new col